# Inserting a quote in a search and replace regex variable

Tags: regex, perl

I've the following string in Perl.

```
$string = "The date is SOMEDATE today";
```

I want to replace SOMEDATE with a the string '2013-05-30' (single quote included). So my expected final value for $string is

```
$string = "The date is '2013-05-30' today";
```

The issue is the date 2013-05-30 is something I put in a variable.

```
$date = "\'2013-05-30\'";
```

So if I do

```
$string =~ s/SOMEDATE/$date/g;
```

I end up with

```
 The date is 2013-05-30 today
```

Note, the single quote is gone. How do I get the single quote in?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a single quote anywhere in the substitution command.

Comment: typo... added that change.

Comment: Hmm, this works for me actually.  I ran your code exactly.

Comment: @broccoli: If the single quotes are in the variable `$date` then there is no reason why this shouldn't work as it is. Please check.

Comment: What you say isn't true. Did you perhaps use `/e` on the substitution? If not, then `$date` doesn't contain the quotes you claim it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you're not really telling us what you do. This should work:

```
$ cat x.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$string = "The date is SOMEDATE today";
$date = "'2013-05-30'";
$string =~ s/SOMEDATE/$date/g;
print "$string\n";

$ ./x.pl
The date is '2013-05-30' today
```